# url_for is not defined in Flask

Tags: python

```
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
from flask import Flask,url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
    sidebar = env.get_template('sidebar.html')
    return tmpl.render(root_url="",sidebar=sidebar.render())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in tempaltes/index.html

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}
```

Though, I get url_for is not defined? I am trying to follow the examples online but I don't know why I get this

Comment: Do i have a broken install or what

Comment: for the sake of argument would you mind trying having the `from flask import url_for` in its own line?

Comment: Did that help or getting same result?

Comment: i am getting the same result

Comment: I believe it is because of jinja2, I believe url_for might only work for render_template with flask

Comment: oh D'oh! yes, I failed to see that the code was inside a jinja template. Absolutely, that code will not work in there.

Comment: Ok i see. I like that Jinja has a template object that can be rendered whenever I want, do you know if flask has this or is there only a `render_template` function?

Comment: You can generate the url in the code, then pass it as part of the rendering object. In the template you can have something like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{obj.js_url}}"></script>`

Comment: Do you mind if I add an answer for this and get some cred?

Comment: You are using Jinja templating a bit non-standard way. Flask itself automatically creates environment for Jinja and you get `url_for` support when using Flask's `render_template()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to have code logic in the jinja html template. Jinja prohibits that, by design, so that code/presentation aren't mixed.

So, I would suggest generating the url in the code, stashing it somewhere in the object you send jinja and then using that variable in the template. Something along the lines of:

```
def hello_world():
    tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
    sidebar = env.get_template('sidebar.html')
    js_url = url_for('static', filename='js/main.js')
    return tmpl.render(root_url="",sidebar=sidebar.render(), jsurl=js_url)
```

Then on the template side:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{jsurl}}"></script>`

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you are using Flask and Jinja in a bit non-recommended way. I suggest that you use `render_template` which also adds access to Flask-specific functions like `url_for`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```